# series of numbers separated by odd and even numbers using python

Tags: python-3.x

a series of numbers each number is separated by odd and even numbers for example: separated by odd numbers(1,3,7,9...) - 1 2 5 10 17 26 37..... and separated by even numbers(2,4,6,8...) - 1 3 7 13 21 31 43.....

i want a python program for these series of numbers, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize a couple of [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.2.html#pep-255-simple-generators):

```
def separated_by_odd_sequence() -> int:
    num = 1
    odd_increment = 1
    while True:
        yield num
        num += odd_increment
        odd_increment += 2


def separated_by_even_sequence() -> int:
    num = 1
    even_increment = 0
    while True:
        num += even_increment
        even_increment += 2
        yield num


def main() -> None:
    separated_by_odd_sequence_gen = separated_by_odd_sequence()
    first_10_separated_by_odd = [
        next(separated_by_odd_sequence_gen) for _ in range(10)
    ]
    print(f'{first_10_separated_by_odd = }')
    separated_by_even_sequence_gen = separated_by_even_sequence()
    first_10_separated_by_even = [
        next(separated_by_even_sequence_gen) for _ in range(10)
    ]
    print(f'{first_10_separated_by_even = }')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
first_10_separated_by_odd = [1, 2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 37, 50, 65, 82]
first_10_separated_by_even = [1, 3, 7, 13, 21, 31, 43, 57, 73, 91]
```

Comment: I have no idea how you did the mental step from this abyssmal question to the solution you provided.  what is the logic here? Is that some kind of "series coding question" you experienced before and recognized?

Comment: Whoops, I introduced a bug in the penultimate edit. Thanks for catching that.